# Authorization methods only works for default guard in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and I'm trying to use `Gate` facade to allow admins to access resources like users. First, I define a gate in `AuthServiceProvider.php` like following:

```
Gate::define('view-users', 'App\Policies\UserPolicy@view');
```

Then, I write `view` method in Policy class like this:

```
public function view(Admin $admin, User $user)
{
    return true;
}
```

And, I apply the authorization like following:

```
//UsersController.php

$user = User::first();
if (Gate::allows('view-users', $user)) {
    $users = User::all();
    return view('admin.users.list', compact('users'));
}
return abort(403);
```

I note that, the `$user` argument is useless variable and I don't need it to perform authorization. 
By the way, when I use `allows()` method of `Gate` facade, it always returns false. While, when I use `denies()` instead, these steps work fine.

what's wrong with `allows()` method?!

However, corresponding to the Laravel Docs,  I tested other ways to apply authorization via `middleware()`, `Model` or `authorize()`. But, I got the same result.

**Edit:**
**I should note that I'm using custom guard named `web_admin`**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your policy method to this:

```php
public function view(User $user)
{
    return $user->isAdmin;
}
```

The first argument of the policy method is always the current authenticated user. Note that you are not required to pass the currently authenticated user to these methods. Laravel will automatically take care of passing the user into the gate Closure:

```php
if (Gate::allows('view-users')) {
    // The current user can view all users...
}
```

If you want to check if the current user can update a specific user your policy method would be:

```php
public function update(User $authenticatedUser, User $beeingEditedUser)
{
    return $authenticatedUser->isAdmin;
}
```

Then authorize like this:

```php
if (Gate::allows('update-user', $beeingEditedUser)) {
    // The current user can update the user...
}
```

If you're using custom guard (according to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460156/policy-methods-never-be-called-and-gateallows-returns-false-in-laravel/59460588#comment105106151_59460588)), you may have 2 options:

1. Use `forUser` method:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Gate::forUser(Auth::guard('web_admin')->user())->allows('view-users')) {
    // The current user can view all users...
}
```

2. Protecting the routes, specifying the guard:

```php
Route::middleware('auth:web_admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
});
```

This causes Larvel to set your default auth driver and resolve the auth user based on your custom guard.

Comment: Thanks to your help. I applied your solution but the problem is remaining. I changed the `view` method to `public function view(Admin $admin){return $admin->isSuperAdmin();}`, So that the `isSuperAdmin()` returns `$this->admin_name === 'particular_name' ?: false;`. I should note this the admins are retrieved on different guard named `web_admin` that I declare it in the `auth.php` of Laravel. I'll appreciate for your next solution.

Comment: I want `if (Gate::allows('update-user')) {return abort(401);}` make more clean code example `Gate::allows('update-user')->abort(401)` or `Permission::can('update-user') `where should i make it? I mean what file and where?